# Playing sound file only once on object detection in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

The below program is an implementation of Air drums using openCV. Blue colored objects are considered as drumsticks, and when these objects are present in the region of interest, then the sound is played. I want the sound to play only once.
As of now, the sound keeps looping and playing back, if I just keep my drumstick in the region of interest(which is what the code is designed to do), but i want to improve it.
I was thinking if there was some way to make the sound play only if the drumstick goes away from the region of interest and comes back.
Any resources or help would be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2
import pygame


def state_machine(sumation,sound):

    # Check if blue color object present in the ROI     
    yes = (sumation) > Hatt_thickness[0]*Hatt_thickness[1]*0.8

    # If present play the respective instrument.
    if yes and sound==1:
        drum_clap.play()
        
    elif yes and sound==2:
        drum_snare.play()

def ROI_analysis(frame,sound):
    

    # converting the image into HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # generating mask for 
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, blueLower, blueUpper)
    
    # Calculating the nuber of white pixels depecting the blue color pixels in the ROI
    sumation = np.sum(mask)
    
    # Function that decides to play the instrument or not.
    state_machine(sumation,sound)

    
    return mask


Verbsoe = False

# importing the audio files
pygame.init()
drum_clap = pygame.mixer.Sound('batterrm.wav')
drum_snare = pygame.mixer.Sound('button-2.ogg')


# HSV range for detecting blue color 
blueLower = (80,150,10)
blueUpper = (120,255,255)

# Frame accusition from webcam/ usbcamera 
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret,frame = camera.read()
H,W = frame.shape[:2]

kernel = np.ones((7,7),np.uint8)

# reading the image of hatt and snare for augmentation.
Hatt = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('./Images/Hatt.png'),(200,100),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
Snare = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('./Images/Snare.png'),(200,100),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)


# Setting the ROI area for blue color detection
Hatt_center = [np.shape(frame)[1]*2//8,np.shape(frame)[0]*6//8]
Snare_center = [np.shape(frame)[1]*6//8,np.shape(frame)[0]*6//8]
Hatt_thickness = [200,100]
Hatt_top = [Hatt_center[0]-Hatt_thickness[0]//2,Hatt_center[1]-Hatt_thickness[1]//2]
Hatt_btm = [Hatt_center[0]+Hatt_thickness[0]//2,Hatt_center[1]+Hatt_thickness[1]//2]

Snare_thickness = [200,100]
Snare_top = [Snare_center[0]-Snare_thickness[0]//2,Snare_center[1]-Snare_thickness[1]//2]
Snare_btm = [Snare_center[0]+Snare_thickness[0]//2,Snare_center[1]+Snare_thickness[1]//2]


time.sleep(1)

while True:
    
    # grab the current frame
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)

    if not(ret):
        break
    
    # Selecting ROI corresponding to snare
    snare_ROI = np.copy(frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1],Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]])
    mask = ROI_analysis(snare_ROI,1)

    # Selecting ROI corresponding to Hatt
    hatt_ROI = np.copy(frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1],Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]])
    mask = ROI_analysis(hatt_ROI,2)

    # A writing text on an image.
    cv2.putText(frame,'Project: Air Drums',(10,30),2,1,(20,20,20),2)
    
    # Display the ROI to view the blue colour being detected
    if Verbsoe:
        # Displaying the ROI in the Image
        frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1],Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]] = cv2.bitwise_and(frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1],Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]],frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1],Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]], mask=mask[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1],Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]])
        frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1],Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]] = cv2.bitwise_and(frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1],Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]],frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1],Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]],mask=mask[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1],Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]])
    
    # Augmenting the instruments in the output frame.
    else:
        # Augmenting the image of the instruments on the frame.
        frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1],Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]] = cv2.addWeighted(Snare, 1, frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1],Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]], 1, 0)
        frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1],Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]] = cv2.addWeighted(Hatt, 1, frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1],Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]], 1, 0)
    
    
    cv2.imshow('Output',frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
 
# cleanup the camera and close any open windows
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this would be to use a boolean to keep track of whether the drumstick has already played sound before. If you want it to just play a sound once upon entering an area, set this flag to True after playing the sound once and reset it to False when it is removed. Here is the same code with a flag added:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2
import pygame

IS_PLAYING = False    # Keeps track of whether sound has been played this "hover" or
                      # not

def state_machine(sumation,sound):

    global IS_PLAYING

    # Check if blue color object present in the ROI     
    yes = (sumation) > Hatt_thickness[0]*Hatt_thickness[1]*0.8
    if yes:
        if not IS_PLAYING:    # If sound has not been played

            # If present play the respective instrument.
            if yes and sound==1:
                drum_clap.play()
                
            elif yes and sound==2:
                drum_snare.play()

            IS_PLAYING = True  # Sound has been played, so we do not need to repeat

    else:    # Mouse is not over the drum-good to play sound again
        IS_PLAYING = False


def ROI_analysis(frame,sound):
    

    # converting the image into HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # generating mask for 
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, blueLower, blueUpper)
    
    # Calculating the nuber of white pixels depecting the blue color pixels in the ROI
    sumation = np.sum(mask)
    
    # Function that decides to play the instrument or not.
    state_machine(sumation,sound)

    
    return mask


Verbsoe = False

# importing the audio files
pygame.init()
drum_clap = pygame.mixer.Sound('batterrm.wav')
drum_snare = pygame.mixer.Sound('button-2.ogg')


# HSV range for detecting blue color 
blueLower = (80,150,10)
blueUpper = (120,255,255)

# Frame accusition from webcam/ usbcamera 
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret,frame = camera.read()
H,W = frame.shape[:2]

kernel = np.ones((7,7),np.uint8)

# reading the image of hatt and snare for augmentation.
Hatt = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('./Images/Hatt.png'),(200,100),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
Snare = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('./Images/Snare.png'),(200,100),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)


# Setting the ROI area for blue color detection
Hatt_center = [np.shape(frame)[1]*2//8,np.shape(frame)[0]*6//8]
Snare_center = [np.shape(frame)[1]*6//8,np.shape(frame)[0]*6//8]
Hatt_thickness = [200,100]
Hatt_top = [Hatt_center[0]-Hatt_thickness[0]//2,Hatt_center[1]-Hatt_thickness[1]//2]
Hatt_btm = [Hatt_center[0]+Hatt_thickness[0]//2,Hatt_center[1]+Hatt_thickness[1]//2]

Snare_thickness = [200,100]
Snare_top = [Snare_center[0]-Snare_thickness[0]//2,Snare_center[1]-Snare_thickness[1]//2]
Snare_btm = [Snare_center[0]+Snare_thickness[0]//2,Snare_center[1]+Snare_thickness[1]//2]


time.sleep(1)

while True:
    
    # grab the current frame
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)

    if not(ret):
        break
    
    # Selecting ROI corresponding to snare
    snare_ROI = np.copy(frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1],Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]])
    mask = ROI_analysis(snare_ROI,1)

    # Selecting ROI corresponding to Hatt
    hatt_ROI = np.copy(frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1],Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]])
    mask = ROI_analysis(hatt_ROI,2)

    # A writing text on an image.
    cv2.putText(frame,'Project: Air Drums',(10,30),2,1,(20,20,20),2)
    
    # Display the ROI to view the blue colour being detected
    if Verbsoe:
        # Displaying the ROI in the Image
        frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1],Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]] = cv2.bitwise_and(frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1],Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]],frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1],Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]], mask=mask[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1],Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]])
        frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1],Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]] = cv2.bitwise_and(frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1],Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]],frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1],Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]],mask=mask[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1],Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]])
    
    # Augmenting the instruments in the output frame.
    else:
        # Augmenting the image of the instruments on the frame.
        frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1],Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]] = cv2.addWeighted(Snare, 1, frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1],Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]], 1, 0)
        frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1],Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]] = cv2.addWeighted(Hatt, 1, frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1],Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]], 1, 0)
    
    
    cv2.imshow('Output',frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
 
# cleanup the camera and close any open windows
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hopefully this answers your question! Feel free to let me know if you have any problems with this answer.

Answer (score -1):

To make the sound play only once when the drumstick goes away from the region of interest and comes back, you can use a flag to keep track of the state. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2
import pygame

def state_machine(sumation, sound, sound_playing):
    # Check if blue color object present in the ROI
    yes = (sumation) > Hatt_thickness[0]*Hatt_thickness[1]*0.8

    # If present and sound is not already playing, play the respective instrument.
    if yes and sound == 1 and not sound_playing[0]:
        drum_clap.play()
        sound_playing[0] = True
    elif yes and sound == 2 and not sound_playing[1]:
        drum_snare.play()
        sound_playing[1] = True
    # If not present, reset the sound playing flag.
    elif not yes:
        sound_playing[0] = False
        sound_playing[1] = False

def ROI_analysis(frame, sound):
    # converting the image into HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # generating mask for blue color
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, blueLower, blueUpper)

    # Calculating the number of white pixels depecting the blue color pixels in the ROI
    sumation = np.sum(mask)

    # Function that decides to play the instrument or not.
    state_machine(sumation, sound, sound_playing)

    return mask

Verbose = False

# importing the audio files
pygame.init()
drum_clap = pygame.mixer.Sound('batterrm.wav')
drum_snare = pygame.mixer.Sound('button-2.ogg')

# HSV range for detecting blue color
blueLower = (80, 150, 10)
blueUpper = (120, 255, 255)

# Frame acquisition from webcam/ usbcamera
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = camera.read()
H, W = frame.shape[:2]

kernel = np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8)

# reading the image of hatt and snare for augmentation.
Hatt = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('./Images/Hatt.png'), (200, 100), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
Snare = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('./Images/Snare.png'), (200, 100), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

# Setting the ROI area for blue color detection
Hatt_center = [np.shape(frame)[1] * 2 // 8, np.shape(frame)[0] * 6 // 8]
Snare_center = [np.shape(frame)[1] * 6 // 8, np.shape(frame)[0] * 6 // 8]
Hatt_thickness = [200, 100]
Hatt_top = [Hatt_center[0] - Hatt_thickness[0] // 2, Hatt_center[1] - Hatt_thickness[1] // 2]
Hatt_btm = [Hatt_center[0] + Hatt_thickness[0] // 2, Hatt_center[1] + Hatt_thickness[1] // 2]

Snare_thickness = [200, 100]
Snare_top = [Snare_center[0] - Snare_thickness[0] // 2, Snare_center[1] - Snare_thickness[1] // 2]
Snare_btm = [Snare_center[0] + Snare_thickness[0] // 2, Snare_center[1] + Snare_thickness[1] // 2]

time.sleep(1)

sound_playing = [False, False]  # Flag to keep track of sound playing state

while True:
    # grab the current frame
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

    if not ret:
        break

    # Selecting ROI corresponding to snare
    snare_ROI = np.copy(frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1], Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]])
    mask = ROI_analysis(snare_ROI, 1)

    # Selecting ROI corresponding to Hatt
    hatt_ROI = np.copy(frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1], Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]])
    mask = ROI_analysis(hatt_ROI, 2)

    # A writing text on an image.
    cv2.putText(frame, 'Project: Air Drums', (10, 30), 2, 1, (20, 20, 20), 2)

    # Display the ROI to view the blue colour being detected
    if Verbose:
        # Displaying the ROI in the Image
        frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1], Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]] = cv2.bitwise_and(
            frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1], Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]],
            frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1], Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]], mask=mask[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1], Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]])
        frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1], Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]] = cv2.bitwise_and(
            frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1], Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]],
            frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1], Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]], mask=mask[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1], Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]])

    # Augmenting the instruments in the output frame.
    else:
        # Augmenting the image of the instruments on the frame.
        frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1], Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]] = cv2.addWeighted(Snare, 1,
                                                                                     frame[Snare_top[1]:Snare_btm[1],
                                                                                     Snare_top[0]:Snare_btm[0]], 1, 0)
        frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1], Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]] = cv2.addWeighted(Hatt, 1,
                                                                                   frame[Hatt_top[1]:Hatt_btm[1],
                                                                                   Hatt_top[0]:Hatt_btm[0]], 1, 0)

    cv2.imshow('Output', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# cleanup the camera and close any open windows
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In this updated code, a `sound_playing` list is added to keep track of the state of each sound (drum_clap and drum_snare). When the drumstick is present in the region of interest, the respective sound will only play if the corresponding sound flag is not already set to True. When the drumstick goes away, the sound flag is reset to False.